# How to exclude underscore from regex group java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am using the name of excel files that can be in this format
  table_A_Apr_2000.xlsx and I want an expression that would give me groups as string object below form

```
                [table_A, Apr, 2000, .xlsx]
```

when I am using this expression in my code

```
       String table="table_A";
     String[] slist = {"table_A_Apr_2001.xlsx"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^"+table+"|\\d+|\\D+|[^_]*");

    for(int i=0; i<slist.length;i++){

        Matcher m = p.matcher(slist[i]);
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(m.find()){
            a.add((m.group()));
        }

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("~~~~~");

    }
```

it gives following output

```
       [table_A, _Apr_, 2001, .xlsx, ]
   but I want it to be like 
       [table_A, Apr, 2000, .xlsx]
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated, especially in the pattern expression part

Comment: Just split on `(?<!^table)[._]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\D` represents every non-digit which includes `_`. To eliminate it create [intersection](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) of `\\D` and `[^_]` sets with `&&` operator. Try using `[\\D&&[^_]]+` instead of `\\D+|[^_]*`

OR since `\D` is negation of `\d`, we can use De Morgan's law that `~p AND ~q` is same as `~(p OR q)` and rewrite it as `[^\\d_]+`.

Comment: Or `[^\d_]` without intersection.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, regex is one of the most mind boggling part of java or for any language I presume.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a formal regex matcher, but one option which might be workable here would be to do an intelligent split of the filename:

```
String filename = "table_A_Apr_2001.xlsx";
filename = filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf('.'));
String[] parts = filename.split("_(?=[^_]{3,})");

System.out.println("table: " + parts[0]);
System.out.println("month: " + parts[1]);
System.out.println("year: " + parts[2]);

table: table_A
month: Apr
year: 2001
```

### Demo